# How to install opencv into multiple python environments?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, cmake

I‘d like use OpenCV in C++ and Python with virtual envs. Is it possible to build Opencv once and put the binaries and headers somewhere global (like /usr/local) and then for python projects with virtual environments just add/link the python bindings to that project interpreter?
Or do I really have to recompile OpenCV every time I want to create a new python env?

I‘ve been trying to better understand the installation process of opencv but I couldn‘t find any documentation of the cmake flags. I‘ve also tried to read the cmake file of the repo, but that is way too complex for my humble cmake skills.

Comment: I can tell you how to do it in python, but I do not know anything about c++, although it isn't like a one liner or anything and assumes you use a .bashrc, is it python2 or python3?

Comment: are you compiling it yourself or installing prebuilds via conda or something like that? I'm using python 3. My idea so far was to compile it with the bindings to the system python and then symlink from the virtual env. don't know if that will work yet

Comment: I am on a Mac so I install using brew globally, then I add openCV site path to the global site path, then create a venv for OpenCV project and point my OpenCV installation so that it can reuse the installation. I have notes of this if you'd like me to post as an answer how I setup the installation and you can take he parts that work for you.

Comment: yes thank you, that sounds like it could work.

Comment: @d_kennetz can you post your notes? that would be helpful. thanks